# Replace string and rest of line with other string

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, find, wildcard

So here's what I want to do:

I have a string origStr, which is at the beginning of a line in a Word document. After origStr is an unknown value (e.g. 23 or 2,6)

I want to find that string and replace the value after with another known value, but keep the string.

Example in my Word document:

```
Diam. diastole, mm: 53
```

[Running VBA makro where user input is 54,3]

Expected Result:

```
Diam. diastole, mm: 54,3
```

Actual result:

```
Diam. diastole, mm: 54,3 53
```

So here's what i got:

```
origStr = LArray(i, j - 1).Caption & ": *"
replStr = LArray(i, j - 1).Caption & ": " & TBArray(i, j).Text

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = origStr
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = replStr
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
End With
```

Why isn't my old value being deleted?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word uses "lazy" pattern matching which is good in this case because otherwise it would just replace  the rest of your entire document. Vincent G gave a solution for one word (no more than one space in the rest of the line), here is something more general:

To get Word to replace everything until the end of the line, you need to include the end of the line into the search string. `^l` or `^11` is the control code for `new line` (shift+enter), `^12` is `page or section break`, `^13` is `carriage return`.
[This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/197855) is the most "recent" list I found.

So `"yourtext*^11"` would match everything from `"yourtext"` until the next `new line` and so on.

Depending on your formatting, it could be either one of the above so you have to be careful. If you replace `"*^12"` but your lines end with `new line`, you will replace the whole paragraph.

To catch all of them, you can group them: `yourtext*[^11^12^13]` will match everything until the next `new line` or `carriage return`. However if we replace that, the end of the line will be replaced as well so we have to include it in the replacement text. How do we know what it was?

We can use `()` to define a submatch and `\1`, `\2` etc to use these submatches in the replacement text:

```
origStr = LArray(i, j - 1).Caption & ": *([^11^12^13])"
replStr = LArray(i, j - 1).Caption & ": " & TBArray(i, j).Text & "\1"
```

Example:

before:
 [image: before]

after replacing with `origStr = "yourtext*([^11^12^13])"` and `replStr = "yourtext newtext\1"`:
[image: after]

---

Note: These expressions also work with the Find and Replace dialog, just make sure "Use Wildcards" is enabled

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Its not really a VBA problem, the same happening in "Find and Replace" dialog.

Replace your original string with:

```
origStr = LArray(i, j - 1).Caption & ": <*>"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't solve it though. Now the result is Diam. diastole, mm: 54,33 (It just removed the first character in the original value)